# Changing width and height of Image inside a datatemplate

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have an image inside datatemplate. I want to change its height and width depending on certain conditions. How can I achieve that?

The XAML code I have:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="options_stack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,569,0,33" Width="603" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" Height="123" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="options_image" Source ="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill" Width="123" Height="123" MaxHeight="123" MaxWidth="123" Tapped="apply_accessory"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1

Since you are binding source property I would create a data structure (to use as DataContext) to hold `Source`, `Width` and `Height` properties and then bind them:

```
<Image x:Name="options_image"
       Source ="{Binding Source}"
       Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"
       MaxWidth="{Binding Width}" MaxHeight="{Binding Height}"
       Stretch="Fill" Tapped="apply_accessory"/>
```

#### Option 2

Another option is to create different **DataTemplates** and a **DataTemplateSelector** to apply when certain conditions are met.

DataTemplateSelector ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx

#### Option 3

If you don't like both above options you have another way of doing it. In my last work *(Taskin, if you want to take a look you can see the link in my profile)* I needed to show different colors for different `ListViewItems`. I didn't want to create a new Property in my `Task` model to hold the color or a `TemplateSelector` just for this. So I created a simple `IValueConverter` instead that uses an already existent `Priority` object property and returns its color. Then I binded it like this:

```
<Border Background="{Binding Priority, Converter={StaticResource priorityToColorConverter}}"/>
```

---

XAML gives you many ways to implement what you want and it is up to you to choose the best and cleanest way to solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: I tried binding height and width. But when I change them in a method, it doesn't work... In my method I write this: 
            optionDimensions op = new optionDimensions();
            op.Height = 123;
            op.Width = 123;
What am I missing?

Comment: did you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`? If you are using a List of `optionDimensions` use an `ObservableCollection<optionDimensions>` instead.

Comment: Yes it worked with the ObservableCollection<optionDimensions>. Thankyou

Comment: Glad it worked. See another alternative I added. It can be usefull to you in the future.